# OSX codesign. Avoid specific resources to be checked

Tags: macos, resources, codesign

In OSX, I have a resource file that contains the checksum of my executable.

Codesigning alters the executable thus if I calculate the checksum after codesign I need the file  storing the result to not be checked (it is located in Resources).

Is there a way to achieve this?, The other option would be programmatically verify codesing at execution time but this looks more complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG206

according to this TechNote, it is not anymore possible to exclude resources from codesign unfortunately.

Comment: I've found that codesigning twice does the trick, one alters the executable, then I calculate my checksum, then re-signing again validates the resources containing my checksum.